# `padding-right` attribute is not adding padding

Tags: html, ejs

Kind of a basic question, but for some reason it is not working for me

I want to add more space between the country name and the country icon, and shift the country icon about 15 pixels to the left of where it is now.

However, every attempt to add a `padding-right` attribute does not seem to be successful. Any thoughts?

```
<div class="Country">
              <img src="/icons/<%= country.icon %>" width="25" height="25" style="padding-right: 5px;" />  <%= country.name %> 
          </div>
```

Note: this is part of an ejs tempalte.

Answer (score 0):

This example works just fine

```
<div>
  <img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1350072692/t1/img/front_page/jp-mountain.jpg" width="25" height="25" style="border: 1px solid green; padding-right: 5px;" />Some image
</div>
```

with 5 pixels visible inside the green border.
Could it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a class to the img tag and give that class a margin-right: 5px;

hopefully that fixes it